# Как перенаправить запрос с http://domain.zone на https://domain.zone и с IPV4 на https://domain.zone?

Tags: apache, http, https, dns

Собственно в этом и есть вопрос. Сейчас у меня есть сайт с доменным именем. В качестве dns использую не свою машину, а dns сторонней компании, но есть возможность добавлять записи. Также мне предоставили SSL для моего домена.

Я Добавил в настройки своего dns A record и CNAME record. Теперь могу найти сайт в браузере 4 способами:

1. `IP` машины, где крутится `apache` и файлы сайта - в браузере `IP`
2. Запрос на `<domain>.com` - в адресной строке `IP`
3. запрос на `www.<domain>.com` - в адресной строке`IP`
4. Прямой запрос на `https://<domain>.com` - в адресной строке `https://<domain>.com`

Вопрос такой: Как теперь можно перенаправить все запросы на `https://<domain>.com`? Какие записи добавить для этого в настройки dns?

Comment: В DNS никакие. Надо править конфигурацию веб-сервера.

Comment: @Alexey Ten К серверу есть полный доступ. Добавить в conf  file redirect-ы?

Comment: А какой собственно веб-сервер? Nginx? Apache? Что-то другое?

Comment: @AlexeyTen apache